# kubectl Unexpected error when reading response body

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubectl, firewall

Update: this is a network issue. Nothing to do with the software stack.

I have a k8s cluster running in another, not-so-secure network, and I am obviously using kubeconfig.

I can do all other stuff, just not `kubectl apply -f`.

The problem is I get - when `kubectl apply -f <file>:`

```
    kubectl  E0914 18:43:57.731039    4053 request.go:1085] Unexpected error when reading response body: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout or context cancellation while reading body)
error: unexpected error when reading response body. Please retry. Original error: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout or context cancellation while reading body)
```

Do you know what to do?

```
kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.0", GitCommit:"a866cbe2e5bbaa01cfd5e969aa3e033f3282a8a2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-23T17:36:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.19", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"25", GitVersion:"v1.25.0", GitCommit:"a866cbe2e5bbaa01cfd5e969aa3e033f3282a8a2", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-08-23T17:38:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.19", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}
```

Comment: Are you facing this only with one particular file ? Or with any resources or commands?

Comment: Good question, yes it is with any -f <file res>

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl version --output=yaml` if this doesn't; work `kubectl version`

Comment: Try adding `--v=9` ([output verbosity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/_print/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging)) to get more details on where the command is failing.

Answer (score 4):

It's maybe a network issue. have you tried using request-timeout option in your command?

```
kubectl apply -f <file> --request-timeout=4s
```

From the documentation:

```
--request-timeout string     Default: "0"
```

The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion - unfortunately it did not help

Comment: It is strang, if it is a network issue - why I can kubectl get long lists back... hmm

Answer (score 1):

This is a network issue, and has nothing to do with the software stack. I found out as other issues started to show up in my network.